# Create a column with Labels to partition DataFrame in Pandas.

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, partitioning, cut

I am strugling a lot finding a tidy way of doing the following.

I have a Pandas DataFrame that looks like that:

```
data = {'Ids': [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3],  'Value': [32, 56, 87, 12, 45, 78, 
14, 21, 56]}
df=pd.DataFrame(data)

Out[2]: 
    Ids  Value
0    1     32
1    2     56
2    3     87
3    1     12
4    2     45
5    3     78
6    1     14
7    2     21
8    3     56
```

I would like to add another column that identifies each sub-set of data (Ids from 1 to 3) with a label. Something like this:

```
Out[3]: 
   Case  Ids  Value
0    A    1     32
1    A    2     56
2    A    3     87
3    B    1     12
4    B    2     45
5    B    3     78
6    C    1     14
7    C    2     21
8    C    3     56
```

I am trying to use pandas.cut() function this way but I am now having lot of success:

```
df["test"]=pd.cut(df1.Value, bins=3, labels=["A", "B", "C"], right=False)
```

Is there a nice and tidy way of achieving what I want using Pandas functions? Thank you!

Answer (score 9):

I think need [`cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) with numpy indexing:

```
a = np.array(["A", "B", "C"])
df['new'] = a[df.groupby('Ids').cumcount()]
print (df)
   Ids  Value new
0    1     32   A
1    2     56   A
2    3     87   A
3    1     12   B
4    2     45   B
5    3     78   B
6    1     14   C
7    2     21   C
8    3     56   C
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `groupby` + `ngroup` + `map`:

```
mapper = {0 : 'A', 1 : 'B', 2 : 'C'}
df['New'] = df.groupby(df.Ids.diff().lt(0).cumsum()).ngroup().map(mapper)
```

Or, using @jezrael's neat indexing trick,

```
mapper = np.array(['A', 'B', 'C'])
df['New'] = mapper[df.groupby(df.Ids.diff().lt(0).cumsum()).ngroup()]
```

```
   Ids  Value Case
0    1     32    A
1    2     56    A
2    3     87    A
3    1     12    B
4    2     45    B
5    3     78    B
6    1     14    C
7    2     21    C
8    3     56    C
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use:

```
l = np.array(list('ABC'))

df['Case'] = l[(df.Ids == 1).cumsum().sub(1)]
```

Output:

```
   Ids  Value Case
0    1     32    A
1    2     56    A
2    3     87    A
3    1     12    B
4    2     45    B
5    3     78    B
6    1     14    C
7    2     21    C
8    3     56    C
```

Comment: (Works assuming it starts from 1)

Answer (score 3):

This work for your sample data

```
df['new']=np.array(['A','B','C']).repeat(len(df)//3)
df
Out[519]: 
   Ids  Value new
0    1     32   A
1    2     56   A
2    3     87   A
3    1     12   B
4    2     45   B
5    3     78   B
6    1     14   C
7    2     21   C
8    3     56   C
```

Comment: _Only_ for the sample data though... may not scale if not all groups have the same number of IDs.

Comment: With Jezrael, coldspeed, and Wen.  A poor nobody like me has a chance of getting an "accept" today.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ yep , base on his sample data and description, should work , if not , he already have your guys genius solutions above  :-)

Comment: @ScottBoston I don't know about accepts, but you have my upvote

Comment: Aww.. schucks.  I feel the "+1" love and it is returned.

Comment: @ScottBoston BTW, it is hard too saw all of us show up under one question, WOW ~ :-)